# How do I convert a `string` of `integers` in `hexadecimal` (and back)?

Tags: delphi, hex

I want to convert a `string` of `integers` in `hexadecimal` (and the opposite).

I've seen the `IntToHex` functions, but it uses a small integer.

For example, I need to convert the number:

```
999888777666555444 in hexadecimal
```

and then the opposite:

```
hexadecimal number in 999888777666555444
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the range you need it to support? Int64 can convert 16 hexadecimal digits, or around 19 or 20 decimal digits. If you need to go beyond this, you'll need to make your own conversion that use a floating point value to store the decimal part.

Comment: In order to give specific advice we need to know what data type you use

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert more than 8-bytes values, you can represent your very-long-integer as array of byte, word, dword or something. In that case you should just convert any particular item and concatenate results. Opposite is the same (only thing you should remember is value should be considered as right-aligned).

Answer (score 0):

converting a arbitrary length buffer to hex:

```
function HexDump(const _Buffer; _Len: integer): string;
type
  PByte = ^Byte;
var
  i: integer;
  p: PByte;
begin
  p := @_Buffer;
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to _Len - 1 do begin
    Result := Result + Long2Hex2(p^);
    Inc(p);
  end;
end;
```

And the utility functions used by this:

```
const
  /// <summary>
  /// String containing all characters that can be used as digits
  /// </summary>
  DIGIT_CHARS: string = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKlMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

function Long2Num(_l: ULong; _Base: Byte; _MinWidth: Integer = 1): string;
var
  m: Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  while _l > 0 do begin
    m := _l mod _Base;
    _l := _l div _Base;
    Result := DIGIT_CHARS[m + 1] + Result;
  end;
  while Length(Result) < _MinWidth do
    Result := '0' + Result;
end;

function Long2Hex(_l: ULong): string;
begin
  Result := Long2Num(_l, 16);
end;

function Long2Hex2(_l: ULong): string;
begin
  Result := Long2Hex(_l);
  if Length(Result) < 2 then
    Result := '0' + Result;
end;
```

These functions are part of my dzlib.

Note: This does not generate the hex numbers as you might expect them, e.g. if you pass an integer to the function like this:

```
var
  IntValue: integer;
begin
  IntValue := $12345678;
  s := HexDump(IntValue, SizeOf(IntValue));
end;
```

You end up with s = '78563412' because Intel processors store integers in little endian format.

Unfortunately the other way round is more difficult, because there is no standard arbitrary length integer type in Delphi. There are some implementations of such a type though.

Comment: Take note, however, that this will convert an integer variable passed in as "const _Buffer" as a BIG-endian integer, whereas Delphi on Intel processors (ie. Windows and MAC) uses LITTLE-endian integers. Ie. an integer value of 1024 ($00000400) will be output as 00040000

Comment: (Actually, passing $12345678 will return 78563412 as output)

Comment: Opps, you are reight @HeartWare